# Joomla 3.x documentation Creating Input forms

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.1

I am unable to get a clean Joomla documentation for developer.

a) Is there a clean documentation/tutorial resource for developer for core api (a version specific will be great)

b) My current issue is that I do not want to use any existing component and want to create a simple extension to perform crud operation on a table (add /edit/delete)

c) How to create html forms /validate it, add/update/delete etc a normal operation in web application. Please point me to any resource specific to 3.X

Comment: create a custom component, create the views to create, remove, update and delete. forms generated in PHP.

Comment: you are right but where are docs for 3.x ? Any good reference ?

Comment: try a component generator. http://joomlacomponentcreator.codelydia.com/index.php - docs are rare. some of 1.7 and 2.5 still apply, but it's difficult to know

Comment: @TheCellarRoom thanks good reference. Its surprising to see lack of docs for such a large prominent open source project.

Comment: The best documenation is the code itself, normally the advice is to just follow the model of the core.  In general people think of com_weblinks as the model to follow, not as complex as content but covers all the important points.

Comment: Component Generator is AMAZINGLY easy to use and saves tons of time, especially if not familiar with building Joomla components in the first place. Worst case, build a simply skeleton of what you need and then look at the files it creates. You can learn most of what you need just from that.

Comment: These component generation tool missing advances features and how to manage those . And there is no `reference` point to a standard official way of handling certain thing . E.g How do you handle model relations ( Many to many e.g ) ? Dose these any of the Core model class provide some level of support e.t.c or model is just a wrapper around a table . .. at lost of questions and I don't see any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Joomla 2.5 is still very relevant for 3.1 for the forms.  You can then also compare with other components such as the weblinks as others have suggested.

http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/

As bare essentials you will need controllers (one for list, one for add/edit), models (list + add/edit), form xml for add/edit, table for list, view controller and view template.

The documentation I linked explains how to add them and is fairly descriptive.  I havn't noticed much different between those docs and the current joomla 3 components.

The only thing you will need to watch out for is that some of the classes need to have the name changed.

In particular the views need to be `JViewLegacy` instead of `JView`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that , but I unlike most of open source projects Joomla fails to provide a reasonable documentation about the internal of the core and its classes. Its seems it has been kept this way intentionally. The core is written well but docs are missing :(